Upgrading from gulp 4 to 5: Error: Writable stream closed prematurely
I'm trying to upgrade from Gulp 4 to Gulp 5 and I'm getting  Error: Writable stream closed prematurely.
Here's the relevant function:
const download = require('gulp-download2');

/**
 * Purgecss can only process downloaded files, not URLs.
 */
function downloadPurgeCssPages () {
  console.log('paths.pageDownloads', paths.pageDownloads);
  return gulp.src([paths.pageDownloads])
    .pipe(download(['https://example.com/home']))
    .pipe(rename(function (path) {
      console.log('renaming', path)
      path.extname = '.html';
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('/var/www/html/theme_tools/purgecss_page_downloads'))
}

In the console, I see "renaming" and the path is correct, but then I get the Error: Writable stream closed prematurely error.  I don't really understand what this error means.
This comment in the gulp issue queue states that streams using {end: false} are unsupported, but I don't understand what that means, either.
Is gulp-download-2 incompatible with gulp 5?
